# Get date of selected slot using fullCalendar control

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have some code where I am trying to grab the date as it relates to the slot selected by a user.  I have tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
$('.fc-agenda-axis.fc-widget-header').on('mousedown', function (e) {
      var clickedTime = $(this).parent().find('th').html();
      // line below returns undefined
      var clickedDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
      // and so does this
      var clickedDate2 = $('calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
      someOtherCoolMethod(clickedDate, clickedTime);
});
```

Any idea why the first attempt to get the date doesn't work?

Additional Info:  I am using the agendaDay view, and the version of fullCalendar is 1.5.4 - we **will** be upgrading to a later version this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick).

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
  alert('Event start: ' + calEvent.start); 
  } 
});
```

If it's no event you can use dayClick.

Comment: [dayClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayClick) sound like OP's need. ;)